# Placing a drawn tikzpicture next to an array of equations

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, arrays

Currently I have this code that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}


\begin{document}

\(\begin{array}{ll}
\sin \theta = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} & \multirow{3}{*}{22} \\
\cos \theta = \dfrac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}} & \\
\tan \theta = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} &
\end{array}\)

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (3,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,2);

\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

\tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](O,A){\textit{adjacent}}
\tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](A,B){\textit{opposite}}
\tkzLabelSegment[above left=2pt](O,B){\textit{hypotenuse}}

\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=none,size=0.3,opacity=.4](O,A,B)% square angle here
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=none,size=0.5,opacity=.4](A,O,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](A,O,B){\(\theta\)}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image 2]

But, I want them to align the triangle to the right of the equations. I tried using multirow, shown in the image as `22`. However, if I copy the `tikzpicture` and replace the `22`, the code fails to compile.

What other method should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing as you're using inline math (`\( .. \)`) all you need to do is to remove the empty line between `\)` and `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Here's a slightly different variant, using `aligned` instead of `array`, and modifying the baseline of the `tikzpicture` for better vertical alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\(\begin{aligned}
\sin \theta &= \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}  \\
\cos \theta &= \dfrac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}  \\
\tan \theta &= \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} 
\end{aligned}\)\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=4ex]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (3,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,2);

\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

\tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](O,A){\textit{adjacent}}
\tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](A,B){\textit{opposite}}
\tkzLabelSegment[above left=2pt](O,B){\textit{hypotenuse}}

\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=none,size=0.3,opacity=.4](O,A,B)% square angle here
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=none,size=0.5,opacity=.4](A,O,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](A,O,B){\(\theta\)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an idea that since these equations are important you would like to have them numbered. To be honest it looks pretty ugly and a bit confusing, but it shows that you can solve it with `minipage` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
%%
\begin{document}
\noindent
Clearly
\begin{equation}
  \tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}
\end{equation}
where
\newline
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{align}
    \sin \theta &= \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}\\
    \cos \theta &= \dfrac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}\\
    \tan \theta &= \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,2);
    % 
    \draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;
    % 
    \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](O,A){\textit{adjacent}}
    \tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](A,B){\textit{opposite}}
    \tkzLabelSegment[above left=2pt](O,B){\textit{hypotenuse}}
    % 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=none,size=0.3,opacity=.4](O,A,B)% square angle here
    \tkzMarkAngle[fill=none,size=0.5,opacity=.4](A,O,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](A,O,B){\(\theta\)}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\newline
Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The picture is created with a too big bounding box, because it extends too far below the word “adjacent”. I found that a correction by 1ex seems sufficient (perhaps there are better methods with TikZ, certainly fixing the baseline isn't because the picture's dimensions wouldn't change.

You can use `aligned` and an `adjustbox` next to it containing the picture, with the aforementioned correction and vertically centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\[ % display the thing
\begin{aligned}
\sin \theta &= \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} \\[1ex]
\cos \theta &= \dfrac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}} \\[1ex]
\tan \theta &= \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}
\end{aligned}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=c,trim=0 1ex 0 0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (3,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,2);
\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;
\tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](O,A){\textit{adjacent}}
\tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](A,B){\textit{opposite}}
\tkzLabelSegment[above left=2pt](O,B){\textit{hypotenuse}}
\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=none,size=0.3,opacity=.4](O,A,B)% square angle here
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=none,size=0.5,opacity=.4](A,O,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](A,O,B){\(\theta\)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]